# Create an unknown number of subsets with specific conditions using R

Tags: r, subset

I am still an R beginner, so please be kind :). There are gaps that occur in my data at unknown times and for unknown intervals. I would like to pull these gaps out of my data by subsetting them. I don't want them removed from the data frame, I just want as many different subsets as there are data gaps so that I can make changes to them and eventually merge the changed subsets back into the original data frame. Also, eventually I will be running the greater part of this script on multiple .csv files so it cannot be hardcoded. A sample of my data is below with just the relevant column:

```
fixType (column 9)

fix
fix
fix
fix
fix
fix
lastvalidfix
0
0
0
0
0
firstfix
fix
fix
fix
fix
lastvalidfix
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
firstfix
```

The code I have now is not functional and not completely correct R, but I'm hoping that it expresses what I need to do. Essentially every time lastvalidfix and firstfix are found in the rows of column 9 I would like to create a subset which would include those two rows and however many rows are between them. If using my sample data above then I would be creating 2 subsets, the first with 7 rows and the second with 12 rows. The number of data gaps in each file varies, so the number of subset and the length will likely be different each time. I realize that each subset will need a unique name which is why I've done the subset + 1.

```
subset <- 0 # This is my attempt at creating unique names for the subsets

for (i in 2:nrow(dataMatrix)) { # Creating new subsets of data for each time the     signal is lost
  if ((dataMatrix[i, 9] == "lastvalidfix") & 
     (dataMatrix[i, 9] == "firstfix")){
        subCreat <- subset(dataMatrix, dataMatrix["lastvalidfix":"firstfix", 9], subset + 1)
  }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
start.idx <- which(df$fixType == "lastvalidfix")
end.idx   <- which(df$fixType == "firstfix")
mapply(function(i, j) df[i:j, , drop = FALSE],
       start.idx, end.idx, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

It will return a list of sub-data.frames or sub-matrices.

(Note: my `df$fixType` is what you refer to as `dataMatrix[, 9]`. If it has a column name, I would highly recommend you use that.)

Comment: Thanks so much, this pretty much works and I followed your advice about using the column name. Only thing is that it seems to loop for an awfully long time (possibly infinitely) and it also sometimes seems to start and end with values other than the ones specified. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Sorry, not infinitely, but it does loop through the matrix multiple times when I think it only needs to once.